# Calculate rows in result set returned by SHOW TABLE EXTENDED

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, resultset

I need to check if given table already exists in `Hadoop` database.

For this purpose I use Hive procedure `SHOW TABLE EXTENDED IN db1 LIKE 'table1';` It works well and returns several rows if table exists.

But in my case I have to count rows in result set Or return zero in the case of empty result set and 1 otherwise. I cannot interact with database via `JDBC` so I have to count rows in statement exactly.

Comment: Do you want to get it done only thru hive query? Mixing some bash would be an easy hack!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm restricted by the query.

Comment: How do you run hive then if not from shell?

Comment: You can redirect the output of the query to `wc -l` to get the count. I cannot think of a way to perform a count on the DDL statement result.

Comment: Or just simply check return code $? variable after `hive -e "describe statement"`

Comment: $? variable will be 0 if table exists

Comment: I'm working with remote database via OTL(ODBC) interface.

Comment: How is your Hive metastore configured? And do you have access to it?

Comment: A have not access to metastore, no idea how it is configured

Answer (score 1):

With some mix of bash,

```
hive -S -e 'show table extended in database like "tablename";' | grep 'tableName' | wc -l
```

You can omit `extended` if the additional information is not required,

```
hive -S -e 'show tables in database like "tablename";' | wc -l
```

This will return 1 if there is a table, 0 if not.